# Linking data structure to qt Tree nodes

Tags: qt, opengl

I am writing a QT GUI Opengl application in which I will transverse a tree structure and render the objects.

Here is the dummy structure for my class which will hold the data for the primitives to be drawn.

Whenever a user clicks on the button to create a shape, I will add a new entry in the tree view and would want to link it to the object that would have the data for drawing the primitive.

```
class Container
{
   private:
     Geometry geom;
     unsigned int texture;
     float x;
     float  y;
     float z;
   public :
    // constructor here

    float getx();
    float gety();
    float getz();
 }
```

Whenever a user creates a new object, a new entry should be added to the tree view and linked to a Container object.

When I transverse through the tree view each node should return the Container object attached to it.

Apologies for not posting any code as I have no idea of how to proceed.

I am looking for some advice or starting point on how to proceed.

Comment: For a starter read this [tree model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start with the [simple tree model example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html),
you can use it as a reference for your solution.

In the `TreeItem` class:
use `Container` as the `data`

Example:

```
class TreeItem
{
public:
    explicit TreeItem(const QList<Container> &data, TreeItem *parentItem = 0);
    ~TreeItem();

    void appendChild(TreeItem *child);

    TreeItem *child(int row);
    int childCount() const;
    int columnCount() const;
    Container data(int column) const;
    int row() const;
    TreeItem *parentItem();

private:
    QList<TreeItem*> m_childItems;
    QList<Container> m_itemData; // The tree item holds the container as the data set.
    TreeItem *m_parentItem;
};
```

You can take it from here, just use the example with your custom data model.

Comment: @shomit, do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: HI Simon i am working on this.I am new to table structure of QT .